# Rails 4.1 route path helper using incorrect id in path generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm working on an upgrade from Rails 4.0.13 to Rails 4.1.16... en route to Rails 5.

`@account` and `@facility` are ActiveRecord model instances, retrieved successfully in the controller `FacilitiesController`

```
@account = #<Account id: 1863133034>
@facility = #<Facility id: 2035637533>
```

`routes.rb` looks like this:

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :facilities do
    get :report
  end
end
```

In Rails 4.1.16 console during the request:

```
> request.env["REQUEST_PATH"]
=> "/accounts/1863133034/facilities/2035637533"

> params
{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"facilities", "account_id"=>"1863133034", "id"=>"2035637533"}

> account_facility_report_path( @account, @facility, {})
=> "/accounts/1863133034/facilities/2035637533/report"


> account_facility_report_path( @account, @facility, params.merge( format: :pdf ) )
=> "/accounts/1863133034/facilities/1863133034/report.pdf?id=2035637533"  # why different facility ID??
```

The facility ID is different now in the generated path. Should be `2035637533`, like in the `_path` request just preceding this last one.

Can someone help me understand the difference in behaviour of the `_path` helper because of the 3rd parameter?

In Rails 4.0, I do not notice this behaviour. The path is generated as expected, with facility ID in the path set to `2035637533`.

Comment: Before you do the last route, is facility still the same id ?

Comment: Yes. @facility remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are merging params, which is merging the id key and setting id to the account id.  Try:

```
account_facility_report_path( @account, @facility, format: :pdf )
```

Comment: So... this actually resolves the problem. Hooray.

I guess passing in any derivative of `params` in the path helper is a bad idea in any case.